# Programmatically copying a CD, byte for byte

Tags: c#, c++, windows-7

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way in which I can just make a byte for byte copy of the data on a CD via programming?  Are there some system calls available that can do this stuff?

I have a CD that is somehow corrupted or otherwise damaged, making some of the files inaccessible through explorer, etc.  I know that there is information on there, and I would like to be able to make a copy of it (even in its damaged state) but of course I can't do that through the file system.

Comment: Sure, you can copy the bits from that medium onto another medium. But I'm not sure how that will help things. You still won't be able to read the copy of the data. The file system will still be corrupted.

Comment: I think A.R. wants to read the data into memory.

Comment: @CodyGray gee, its almost like I mentioned that in the question.  Should I make note that I want the raw data so I can attempt a repair?

Comment: Title an content are not in sync. Bitwise copy or bytewise?

Comment: Do you want to know how to retrieve the data, or copy the data? If it's the former then ask on SU and you'll have better luck.

Comment: @Pubby Copy -> Like it says in the question.

Comment: On Linux all it would take is `dd if=/dev/sr0 of=outputfile.bin`. On Windows probably you have to mess with the special files `\\.\PhysicalDriveN` as described [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100027/en).

Comment: @A.R. - As Cody eluded to, if the CD is damaged to the extent that the file system of the disk is unreadable (in other words it no longer contains the information needed to know where the files are located),  then any attempt to salvage the data will likely just result in garbage anyway.

Comment: On windows you can use software for recording protected CD like Clone CD or Alcohol 120% to create disk image. And when you have this image you can try to extract files from it using UltraISO for example or write your own soft to handle ISO9660 filesystem.

Comment: @Alf: "Off-topic" != "I don't understand"...

Comment: @Oli: in this case "I think it's off-topic" == "I don't understand anything here"

Comment: @Alf: The most likely solution to the OP's problem is with existing tools, rather than low-level programming.  He'd have better luck asking at e.g. superuser.com

Comment: Why was this migrated to superuser? The mods there were not happy and I had to reverse the migration. It isn't a *great* question, but it's not something you can easily find the answer for. And it *is* a programming question.

Comment: @Null: I was one of the 5 voters-to-close; I had assumed that what the OP was really interested in was copying a damaged CD (apparently I wasn't the only one who misinterpreted the aim of the question).  I've now tweaked the question title and paragraph order to make it explicit.

Comment: ¤ This [old KB article about Windows 95](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137813) says "Win32 applications on Windows NT use CreateFile() and ReadFile() to read sectors from compact discs". Perhaps you can get there from there. Check out docs. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thanks for a good laugh. your comments paraphrased to expose the meat of it: "you think you're better than anyone else, an ungood person", "you are ranting about something, like an ungood person", "your comments are not constructive". have you thought about whether maybe negative personal attacks are very constructive?

Comment: Will somebody PLEASE think of the children

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: i fail to see why you think the deletion of the highest rated comment was good. even with the labels you try to affix. you're right though that the comment, pointing out that refusing others the possibility of answering something you can't answer yourself is not very social, posed an implicit question of *why* they do that; you evidently think the answer was lack of intelligence, while i think that lack of intelligence is just one possible answer, with herd instinct much more likely (as I see it). cheers,

Comment: Oh dear, even more of the SO history revision. Hirr. :-)

Comment: aww rats!  I wish I could see all of those deleted comments.. =(

Answer (score 2):

A CD frame is 2352 bytes. For a data CD, this is 2048 bytes of data + miscellaneous headers and ECC, but you can read most of the raw frame data.  The drive may trim off a few bytes.  So bypassing the ISO 9660 filesystem and reading the CD in raw mode is your best bet.  Reads will fail with an error on unrecoverable frames, but you may be able to seek past them and just start reading the next frame.

On linux you would open the low level SCSI device, issue an ioctl to set CDROMREADRAW and use read and lseek as required.

Description of CD programming guts is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.5/include/linux/cdrom.h).

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms901381.aspx) has info on reading CDROM on Windows, but does not explain whether it is returning raw data or not.

Comment: Yeah, that is really nice, but the question is in terms of 'Windows'

Comment: Windows has a CDROM read API, so I added a link to it, but I don't know if it will get you raw data.  Use the best tool for the job.